# Cannot compile when importing Processing library into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, processing

I am trying to build a program using the Processing library in eclipse. The process should be relatively straightforward but I cannot compile even an empty processing program. I think the problem may be something to do with my classpaths, I'm not sure. I have attempted to import the processing library and write the simple program several times on both Eclipse and IntelliJ with no luck.

This is the program:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Processing extends PApplet {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       PApplet.main("Processing", args);

   }
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/QuitHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3139)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3266)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10716)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10513)
    at Processing.main(Processing.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 8 more
```

I've uninstalled the java JDK and reinstalled it but it did not make a difference. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, I cant seem to find anyone else online with the exact same problem.

Comment: Looks like you have your Eclipse Installed JREs set up wrong.

Comment: @chrylis How would I go about fixing this? Do I just need to have Eclipse point to the right location of the JRE?

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem after upgrading to JDK 9. I reported it as an issue here (https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5371), and received confirmation that Processing 3 is incompatible with v9. For now, the only workaround is to downgrade to v8.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18537597)

Comment: Now that I have answered the question, would you please remove this comment?

Comment: Thanks @A.Greyson you really helped me on this one

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/QuitHandler
```

Means Processing cannot use internal MacOS API any more, so I found on Processing forum, solved problem for me.

> After digging around I found that the internal Mac APIs that
> Processing has been misusing to add a proper quithandler and set a
> dock icon has now been removed and replaced by official AWT APIS.
> There is a class inside Processing called ThinkDifferent that is
> loaded by reflection when Mac is detected and this class was calling
> the now removed APIs. To solve this I reimplemented this class using
> the new official APIs and just added a new
> processing.core.ThinkDifferent class to my project that solved the
> issue.

```
package processing.core;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Taskbar;
import java.awt.desktop.QuitEvent;
import java.awt.desktop.QuitHandler;
import java.awt.desktop.QuitResponse;

public class ThinkDifferent {

  // True if user has tried to quit once. Prevents us from cancelling the quit
  // call if the sketch is held up for some reason, like an exception that's
  // managed to put the sketch in a bad state.
  static boolean attemptedQuit;

  public static void init(final PApplet sketch) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    desktop.setQuitHandler(
        new QuitHandler() {
          @Override
          public void handleQuitRequestWith(QuitEvent e, QuitResponse response) {
            sketch.exit();
            if (PApplet.uncaughtThrowable == null && !attemptedQuit) {
              response.cancelQuit();
              attemptedQuit = true;
            } else {
              response.performQuit();
            }
          }
        });
  }

  public static void cleanup() {
    Desktop.getDesktop().setQuitHandler(null);
  }

  // Called via reflection from PSurfaceAWT and others
  public static void setIconImage(Image image) {
    Taskbar.getTaskbar().setIconImage(image);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very cool idea!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on my Mac with eclipse projects.
But processing app was compiling fine by itself.
So I looked up in processing app contents and found the jdk it uses (located in Processing/Contents/Plugins/ )
So I used it as my jdk with my project and it worked!

(I also installed the required libs (opengl ones) specified in core.jar contents (opened with Keka))

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot compile even an empty processing program.

This is not a compiler error. This is a runtime error.

Anyway, like [chrylis mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343612/cannot-compile-when-importing-processing-library-into-eclipse#comment81639263_47343612), this is because your classpath is not correct. How you fix this depends on which IDE you're using, but in eclipse you would right-click your project, then click properties, then go to the `Java Build Path` section on the left. Then go to the `Libraries` tab and add the Processing jars.

My guess is that you've added `core.jar`, which is all you need to compile your code. But since you're running on a Mac, you need the Mac-specific jars as well. You'll have to look in your Processing installation directory. Sorry I can't be more specific, but I don't have a Mac.